# Elegant way to prevent global CSS styles from being inherited by views (C#, ASP)

Tags: c#, design, asp.net, css

I've been working on a web app that's divided up into different web pages (around 20). It's only used within my company and it looks at financial data. It's a few years old and is in dire need of an overhaul.

Over the past few months I've been tweaking it and the plan is to completely revamp its styling and a lot of the functionality. I've converted two pages so far and have created a style guide in order to create uniformity.

Much of the project is built with C# and ASP.NET---the CSS files exist at the root level and the `cshtml` pages inherit whatever the CSS is.

The issue we're having is that if we push our `Global.css` file and converted pages to prod, the CSS file will affect the rest of the app. We want to push the converted pages to prod in order to see how they'll behave, but we don't want the Global styles to interfere with pages that we haven't converted yet.

So far I've come up with two possible solutions as to how to handle these issues:

**One**

- Keep `Global.css`
- Set classes based on the categories they belong to

  - e.g. Give all `Coll` tables the class `”.tbl__coll”` and give all AR tables the class `”.tbl__ar”`
  - Styles would bleed into other pages, but only within their respective categories
- Separate the CSS selectors in `Global.css`
- Some styles would remain the same across all pages, e.g. buttons
- Use IDs sparingly

**Two**

- Keep `Global.css` but comment everything out
- Take styles from `Global` and put them back into the two pages I converted (would be in `<style>` tags)
- For future page conversions, add `<styles>` to the cshtml and update `Global` simultaneously

  - When the time comes to remove the styles from the `cshtml`, the styles in `Global` can be brought back

---

I think that Option 2 is looking more likely, but I'm considering taking Option 1 and implementing it alongside 2.

Any thoughts? Let me know if anything needs clarification.

Comment: How about using a `Global2.css` for the new pages and keeping `Global.css` only for the old pages?

Comment: Hey @pschill - I ended up going with something similar to what you said and loading `Global.css` conditionally (for the newer pages). If the url doesn't match a new page, then it loads the older `Site.css`